# How to return plpgsql function as table?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have three input tables and would like to return the result in a new table. Below is the code

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION vrg.VRGTest(_tbl1_VRG regclass,_tbl2_urban regclass,_tbl3_postcodes regclass)
RETURNS table (
    PostcodeName text,
    vrgid double precision,
    urban_gid integer,
    vrg_area double precision,
    urban_area double precision,
    weights double precision
    )AS
      $BODY$
      BEGIN
      EXECUTE format
         ('SELECT
             postcodes.name as PostcodeName,
             fishnet.fid as vrgid, 
             urban.gid as urban_gid, 
             st_area(fishnet.geom) as vrg_area,
             ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(urban.geom, fishnet.geom)) as urban_area,
             ST_AREA(ST_INTERSECTION(urban.geom, fishnet.geom))/st_area(fishnet.geom) as weights
         FROM '   || _tbl1_VRG       ||  'AS fishnet,'
              || _tbl2_urban     || 'as urban,'
              || _tbl3_postcodes || 'as postcodes
         WHERE 
             ST_INTERSECTS(urban.geom, fishnet.geom) and ST_INTERSECTS(fishnet.geom, postcodes.geom)')

       END;   
       $BODY$ LANGUAGE PLPGSQL;
```

The query executes successfully but when I call the function

```
select vrg.VRGTest( 'bb_sumatrapart_grid_1000m','ghs_pop_indonesia_v2_reclass_poly_union_v2_projected','gfk_2016_id_5_digit_pcd_areas2013_projected')
```

I get the error "relation does not exist" I even tried giving the schema name as prefix but no luck.

Comment: Can you post the query result that you mention executes successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space before providing the table alias (for the 3 of them)

```
FROM '   || _tbl1_VRG       ||  'AS fishnet,'
```

--> the `AS` is concatenated, so `inputtable` becomes `inputtableAS` which does not exist.

Change it to

```
FROM '   || _tbl1_VRG       ||  ' AS fishnet,'
```